# How can I find a Ruby method dependencies?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to get the list of methods that implement a Ruby method when this method is invoked?

For example:

```
def foo
  puts "foo"
end

def foo2
  foo
end
```

I want to know that when calling "foo2" it calls 1st "foo" and 2nd "puts" and the corresponding files these methods are defined into. (If "puts" calls other methods, I would like to know them too)

Is that possible? and if 'yes' how? I could say that my question is about finding the method dependencies.

Comment: You're likely to catch flak for trying to do this; it's not a method's responsibility to know who can call it (or who has called it, for that matter). You might want to share your goal/problem and see if there aren't more suitable solutions and help ease concerns anybody has regarding helping write bad code. :)

Comment: Static control flow analysis is pretty hard for a dynamic language like Ruby.

Comment: Sounds like a hack. If you need actions to be in a specific order, why not put them in the same method so that it's clear? Perhaps you're asking a different question, but your example code does't make it clear *why* you want to enforce a static flow. Do you have a more real-world example?

Comment: I do not want to enforce something or have actions in specific order. I just want to find the dependencies of a method. It is part of analysis of code.

Comment: Static control flow analysis is hard, period. Actually, *any* static analysis is hard. Pretty much everything you would want to know statically is either equivalent to the Halting Problem, the Function Problem, subject to Rice's Theorem or some other undecidable problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort of get this using [set_trace_func](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-set_trace_func), but since Ruby is dynamic you would also need test code to call the methods so that the call order is printed.

```
set_trace_func proc { |event, filename, line, id, binding, klass| puts "#{klass}##{id}" }
```

In Ruby 2.0, [TracePoint](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/TracePoint.html) is a superior alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Static code analysis, especially one you'd like to perform (listing all methods called within a method), is very hard in ruby (close to impossible) because the language is dynamic and allows for very strong metaprogramming techniques. Even the parser itself doesn't know the methods required until it tries to execute the code.

Example: calling eval with code read from a file.

Comment: So, I suppose that your answer is 'no', there is no way I can do that. I can accept that as an answer, but let us give some more time to other fellows in order to collect other possible answers.